# Salesforce.com: User cannot edit a note that he added to an account that he doesn't own

Tags: salesforce, user-permissions

I have a user that is trying to edit a note that he created within an account that he doesn't own.  He's getting the following error:

Insufficient Privileges
You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers!
Rommel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viewed User Detail of the owner of the Account.
Added the user that wanted to update the note as a 'Default Account Team' member
Since he is an Inside Sales Rep, his Team Role is Inside Sales Rep
This way, every time the owner of the account creates a brand new account, the user that wants to edit a note will be automatically added.

Also had to check two checkboxes:

- Automatically add my default account team to accounts that I create or accounts that are transferred to me
- Update account teams with these members

Thanks again eyescream!

Cheers!
Rommel

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to grant the user right to Edit this particular Account. By sharing rule (or if it's incidental) by [Sharing] button or (hardcore) just give him "Modify All Data" ;)

As with any Master-Detail situation you need to be able to work with parent and this somehow cascades to child records.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=notes.htm&language=en_US

> You cannot edit a note or attachment unless you also have access to
>   edit the record associated with it.
>
> To delete a note or attachment,
>   you must be the owner of the note or attachment or an administrator
>   with the “Modify all Data” permission. Note ownership is determined by
>   the owner field. Attachment ownership is determined by the created by
>   field.